# Joining datasets using foverlaps

Tags: r

I have two datasets that I would like to join based on the timestamp range. The timestamp doesn't always match in both data frames. Therefore, I would like to join based on a range. I have been advised to us foverlaps.

I'm using this code below but it isn't working not sure how to fulfill all the parameters:

```
                  ~timestamp,                                ~hostname,   ~gpuSerial,                                   ~gpuUUID, ~powerDrawWatt, ~gpuTempC, ~gpuUtilPerc, ~gpuMemUtilPerc,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:27.242Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.94,       32L,           0L,              0L,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:29.259Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:31.285Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:33.301Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.94,       32L,           0L,              0L,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:35.322Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L
  )

tibble::tribble(
                  ~timestamp,                                ~hostname,      ~eventName, ~eventType,                                            ~jobId,                                ~taskId,
  "2018-11-08T07:41:45.459Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",   "TotalRender",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
  "2018-11-08T07:41:45.459Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", "Saving Config",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
  "2018-11-08T07:41:32.461Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",        "Render",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
  "2018-11-08T07:41:32.461Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", "Saving Config",     "STOP", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
  "2018-11-08T07:42:09.344Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",        "Render",     "STOP", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67"
  )

     require(data.table)
     simple example:
     x = data.table(df2,start=c(timestamp),end=c(taskId))
     y = data.table(df1,start=c(timestamp),end=c(gpuMemUtilPerc))
     setkey(y,start,end)
     foverlaps(x, y, by.x = c("timestamp","hostname"), type="within", nomatch = 0L)
```

I would like to be able to get the timestamp for within the range of the timestamp? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt 2**

It appears `fuzzyjoin` gives you a lot of duplicate matchs, so instead lets try and pull the data we want from `df1` into `df2` using `map` and nested tibbles

```
## load library and set data options
library(tidyverse)
options(digits.secs = 3)

## nest a filtered df1 in df2$df
 dat <-
  df2 %>%
  group_by(timestamp, hostname, eventName, eventType) %>%
  mutate(df = map(timestamp, ~ df1 %>% filter(between(timestamp, .x - 2, .x + 2)))) # 4 second interval


  ## walkthrough column df pulling out matching data, averaging multiple matches
  dat %>%
    mutate(
      vals = map2(
        df,
        timestamp,
        ~ if (nrow(.x) == 0)
          NA
        else
          .x %>% mutate(diff = timestamp - .y) %>% filter(diff == min(diff)) %>% summarise(
            powerDrawWatt = mean(powerDrawWatt),
            gpuTempC = mean(gpuTempC)
          )
      ),
      powerDrawWatt = unlist(vals)['powerDrawWatt'],
      gpuTempC = unlist(vals)['gpuTempC']
    ) %>%
    select(-df,-vals)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Groups:   timestamp, eventName, eventType [5]
  timestamp               hostname                               eventName     eventType jobId                                           taskId                               powerDrawWatt gpuTempC
  <dttm>                  <chr>                                  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>                                           <chr>                                        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2018-11-08 07:41:45.459 04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000 TotalRender   START     1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705 00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67          29.9       34
2 2018-11-08 07:41:45.459 04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000 Saving Config START     1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705 00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67          29.9       34
3 2018-11-08 07:41:32.460 04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000 Render        START     1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705 00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67          25.8       32
4 2018-11-08 07:41:32.460 04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000 Saving Config STOP      1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705 00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67          25.8       32
5 2018-11-08 07:42:09.344 04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000 Render        STOP      1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705 00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67          NA         NA
```

**Data**

```
## create tibbles
df1 <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~timestamp,                                ~hostname,   ~gpuSerial,                                   ~gpuUUID, ~powerDrawWatt, ~gpuTempC, ~gpuUtilPerc, ~gpuMemUtilPerc,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:27.242Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.94,       32L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:29.259Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:31.285Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:33.301Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.94,       32L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:44.600Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          29.94,       34L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:42:11.500Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          21.94,       36L,           0L,              0L,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:35.322Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", 323217056165, "GPU-a1119ee9-9cd1-919f-a479-b902142c717d",          25.84,       32L,           0L,              0L
  ) %>% 
  mutate( timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ', tz = 'UTC')  )

df2 <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~timestamp,                                ~hostname,      ~eventName, ~eventType,                                            ~jobId,                                ~taskId,
    "2018-11-08T07:41:45.459Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",   "TotalRender",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
    "2018-11-08T07:41:45.459Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", "Saving Config",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
    "2018-11-08T07:41:32.461Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",        "Render",    "START", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
    "2018-11-08T07:41:32.461Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000", "Saving Config",     "STOP", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67",
    "2018-11-08T07:42:09.344Z", "04dc4e9647154250beeee51b866b0715000000",        "Render",     "STOP", "1024-lvl12-7e026be3-5fd0-48ee-b7d1-abd61f747705", "00390eee-c26c-41da-a02d-556bb7fcac67"
  ) %>% 
  mutate( timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ', tz = 'UTC')  )
```

To round your data,

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    timestamp = lubridate::round_date(timestamp, '10 seconds')
    ) %>% 
    group_by(timestamp, hostname, gpuSerial, gpuUUID) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean)
```

An example of how big of an impact summarizing you data may have:

```
sec_interval <- seq(as.POSIXct('2018-11-08 00:00:0.01', tz = 'UTC'), as.POSIXct('2018-11-08 12:00:01', tz = 'UTC'), by = 0.01)
sec_interval_rounded <- lubridate::round_date(test, '10 seconds') %>% unique()
> length(sec_interval)
[1] 4320100
> length(sec_interval_rounded)
[1] 4321
```

Comment: Many Thanks! for this! This worked for my sample data above but when i try it on my full dataset I am getting the message Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.7 Gb. Is there anyway round this? I

Comment: How many observations do you have in you dataset? Can you join by an additional column as well, or use a stricter timestamp range? Are you only interested in those values that have a match?

Comment: I have one file that contains 660400 and the other one 1543681. There isn't any other column that I can use which available in both datasets. I am mainly interested in the values for the power draw and temperature. How can use stricter times? Thanks for your help

Comment: When I say stricter timestamp range, I mean adjusting the `+/- 0.15` to something smaller such as `+/- 0.015` etc. The issue is that there are too many matches, thus resulting in a very large vector.

Comment: I have tried different values, but the issue still exists. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have given it another try, this time I nest a tibble of matches inside `df2` and work from there. Give it a try, you may need to adjust the grouping.

Comment: Thanks again! Applying this to my datasets takes a long time then crashes with a similar error message regarding the vector size. I'm wondering if there is a way to read the data in small sections then dumping into a data frame?

Comment: Are you able to round the timestamps to the nearest second, or minute, then take the average of the variables? I think that help with size of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Are you able to give me an example of how to round timestamp? I cannot round by hours as my data changes within seconds. So, 10-20 second range would be okay.

Comment: I placed a brief example in my answer above